# How to separate changes from master into another branch without overwriting history?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Recently I have started to implement new experimental feature for my project. Unfortunately I forgot to branch before starting and pushed several commits onto shared repository server into the master branch. Since some other people may have already checked my commits out I would like to avoid overwriting the history on the server.

Due to my changes the master is currently unstable, which is also not good. Therefore I would like to revert changes made to master, create a separate branch that will contain these changes and still be able to reintroduce (merge) them back to master once they are stable enough.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/17595353 and the excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to the problem while I was writing the question. I describe the solution in hope that it may be useful to someone in future. For all the changes I was using gitk and git-gui. I recommend you to do the same as it's much easier than using command line and you will have a visual understanding of what is going on. Here are the steps that I have taken:

1. Perform hard reset to the last stable commit. This will remove all unstable changes from the index and working directory.
2. Perform mixed reset onto last commit on the shared server. This will reset the index to the current commit on the shared server, but will keep the working directory in stable state.
3. Commit all the changes in the working directory. You will then have commit that will cancel all the unstable changes on the master.
4. Create experimental branch at this commit and check it out. At this point experimental branch will have no experimental code, so let's fix this.
5. Cherry pick all commits that should go into experimental branch. This way you will reintroduce back these changes on the experimental branch. Make sure not to cherry-pick last commit that we have just made. If using gitk, it will show a warning that you are trying to cherry-pick the commit that was in the branch already - ignore these warning and proceed.
6. Viola. You are done.

To be safe, I recommend you to make all changes locally and push them only when you are done and sure that everything is correct. Then in case of an error you can always delete the repository and clone it again from the shared server.

Comment: I'm confused: your question explicitly says you want to *avoid overwriting the history on the server*, then you begin with a hard reset, and proceed to write different history...

Comment: @Jefromi: The second step (mixed reset) prevents it from actually rewriting any history (it points HEAD back to the last shared commit, so the commit in the next step builds on top of the shared history). An alternative is a double checkout instead: `git checkout master && git checkout last-stable -- .` (the first positions HEAD to build off the shared history, the second restores the index and working tree to the contents of `last-stable`).

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the command line tools and takes a different approach to managing the branches. It may be less confusing than using multiple resets of various flavors.

The `revert` command in Git 1.7.2 and later can revert multiple commits in one command:

```
git revert last-stable..
```

This will create revert commits for each commit after `last-stable` up to, and including, the current HEAD commit (in reverse order). If you are dealing with many unwanted commits, then you may want to revert them all in a single commit:

```
git revert -n last-stable..
git commit # edit the message to explain that you are reverting multiple commits
```

---

Here is how to put that together with some other commands to re-establish your experimental branch on top of the revert commit(s):
(assumes that the shared branch is named `master`)

```
# Make sure we have the latest shared master
git checkout master
git pull

# Mark the last experimental commit
git branch experimental

# Revert the experimental commits
git revert last-stable.. # optionally use -n and manually commit batched reverts

# Replay the experimental commits on top of the reverted commits
git checkout -B experimental master
git cherry-pick last-stable..experimental@{1}
```