# Retroactively treat line of Git commits as a branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-rebase, pull-request

A bunch of questions ask how to rewrite (`rebase`) some commits so that they appear on a branch, but these all seem to assume that rebase is actually necessary, i.e. that the commits wanted for the branch are interspersed with commits wanted on `master` (whether made by “you” or others).

This question is simpler: I have a clone of a repository on the `master` branch, and I made a bunch of commits intending to create a GitHub pull request. Normally I would have run

```
git checkout -b new-feature
```

*before* starting the commits, but in this case I forgot. Can I retroactively mark this sequence as commits as being on a new branch (without needing to use `git rebase`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the commits to a branch and reset your master branch to where it was with:

```
git branch new-feature
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that this will blow away any uncommitted changes, if that is a problem you should use `git stash` before starting to save them away.

Comment: Sounds like a simpler version of my self-answer, omitting the checkout of the new branch. Will try it next time I get into this situation.

Comment: Yes, this is simple and it works. Also may want to add e.g. `git checkout new-feature && git push fork new-feature && git checkout master`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `fork` is a remote for your GitHub fork:

```
git checkout -b new-feature origin/master
git reset --hard master
git push fork new-feature
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I.e.:

1. Create the new branch, rooted at the upstream tip.
2. Force it to contain what was previously committed on `master`.
3. Push the branch to the forked repository in preparation for a pull request.
4. Go back to the `master` branch.
5. Delete the new commits from it.

Maybe not the most elegant solution but appears to work. Might also want to pass `--set-upstream` to the `push`.